Update SPO App and deploy?
I am not a programmer but have been researching for a couple days.  I am a bit stuck and am seeking guidance.  Cliff notes are below.

I need to update a custom header webpart in SPO. I have the entire package and files from the 3rd party company & I have SPO admin rights.
I know the TS code that needs to be updated but I am very confused on what file(s) need the actual update.  Is the “ master-application-customizer.js” the only file that gets updated?  Or does the .xml file(s) get updated as well?

Do all the files need to be in a certain location or structure to run the gulp process?
There are so many different files in the folders but I believe only the master client side JS is what gets updated.
